# Trying to bubble sort a linked list by only rearranging pointers. My code has a workaround for a 2 node list that I want to get rid of

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

My sort function works but I had to make a workaround for the case where there are only two nodes in the list. Was wondering if someone could help me fix my sorting algorithm so it handles all cases including this one. The function accepts a pointer to a node (which is the head of the list) and then returns a pointer to a node (the new head). The Nodes contain a C string which is 5 characters including the null terminating character and a pointer called `next`.

```
Node *sortList(Node *head) {
    Node *prevNode, *currNode, *tempNode;
    int wordCount = 1;
    int i;

    // make sure the list is not empty 
    // and has more than one node
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        return head;
    }

    currNode = head;
    // find out how many nodes there are
    while (currNode->next != NULL) {
        wordCount++;
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
    // workaround for lists with two items
    if (wordCount == 2) {
        if (strcmp((head->word), (head->next->word)) > 0) {
            tempNode = head->next;
            head->next->next = head;
            head->next = NULL;
            head = tempNode;
            return head;
        } else {
            return head;
        }
    }
    // bubble sort
    for (i = 1; i < wordCount; i++) {
        currNode = prevNode = head;
        while (currNode->next != NULL) {
            if (strcmp((currNode->word), (currNode->next->word)) > 0) {
                tempNode = currNode->next;
                currNode->next = currNode->next->next;
                tempNode->next = currNode;
                if (head == currNode) {
                    head = prevNode = tempNode;
                } else {
                    prevNode->next = tempNode;
                    currNode = tempNode;
                }
            }
            prevNode = currNode;
            currNode = currNode->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I have not understood why you need a workaround if the function works as you are saying?

Comment: I would like my workaround to not be necessary. I don't want to have a specific case where I have a different sorting algorithm. I want my algorithm to work for all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play a classic trick: take a pointer `head` and make it subsequently point to the `next` member of the previous node:

```
Node *sortList(Node *head) {
    // make sure the list is not empty 
    if (head != NULL) {
        // bubble sort
        for (;;) {
            int swapped = 0;
            Node **linkp = &head;
            Node *currNode = head;
            Node *nextNode;

            while ((nextNode = currNode->next) != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(currNode->word, nextNode->word) > 0) {
                    currNode->next = nextNode->next;
                    nextNode->next = currNode;
                    *linkp = currNode = nextNode;
                    swapped++;
                }
                link = &currNode->next;
                currNode = nextNode;
            }
            if (swapped == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

The algorithm is still *Bubblesort* with its inefficient `O(n2)` time complexity, but I used an better test for completion: you no longer need to count the number of elements in the list, just checking if any nodes were swapped during the scan phase is enough. This algorithm also works for a singleton, so you no longer need to special case that either.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a question. Is there an advantage using for ( ; ; ) over while(1)? Also I never would have thought to increment next node within the statement `while ((nextNode = currNode->next) != NULL) {` I'll have to remember that for future projects

Comment: `for (;;)` is idiomatic for an infinite loop.  `while (1)` is less obvious, especially if you have a variable named `l`, where it could be confused with `while (l)` (conclusion: do not name a variable `l` either).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
            if (head == currNode) {
                head = prevNode = tempNode;
                // here
            } else {
                prevNode->next = tempNode;
                currNode = tempNode;
            }
```

In the `if` case where you have to swap the first two elements, `prevNode` is pointing to the new head but `currNode` is unchanged, pointing to the next element.  Then later when you move up `prevNode` and `currNode`, you move `currNode` two elements past `head` instead of just one.  If you have only two elements in the list, `currNode` then points to `NULL` and accessing `currNode->next` at the top of the loop causes a core dump.

After reassigning `head`, add `currNode = tempNode;`:

```
            if (head == currNode) {
                head = prevNode = tempNode;
                currNode = tempNode;
            } else {
                prevNode->next = tempNode;
                currNode = tempNode;
            }
```

Alternately:

```
            if (head == currNode) {
                head = prevNode = tempNode;
            } else {
                prevNode->next = tempNode;
            }
            currNode = tempNode;
```

Once you do that, you can get rid of the special case of two elements.

Comment: For a two-element list, the only one of those cases ever exercised is the `head == currNode` case, which is not problematic.  The special case is absolutely superfluous, as can be demonstrated by experiment.

Comment: When experimenting, the case of two elements does crash the program on my end. If I enter AAA into the second node and BBB into the head node it crashes. It works fine the other way around. It might be worth noting that this function also is sorting reverse alphabetically.

Comment: @lukesau, I don't know what to tell you: I tested it myself, and it worked fine.  I even ran it under `valgrind` to check that there weren't any invalid pointer accesses that I happened to luck out on.  I had to provide a `main()` and a suitable definition of `Node`, but the only change I made to the code you presented was to comment out the `if (wordCount == 2)` block.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It crashed on me when I tested it.  I'll take another look.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Verified it crashes.  On the second iteration of the `while` loop, `currNode` is `NULL`.

Comment: @dbush, well, shoot.  I wonder what else I changed to make it work.  I already discarded the code.